# How can i start new android game project of cocos2d-x-3.17 in visual studio 2017?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.17

I'm new with cocos2d-x-3.17, and i want to start a new android game project, and i prefer developt it in Visual Studio 15/17. I tried to do some search on forum, but unfortunately got me confused.

I already did install coco2d-x-3.17, i used https://docs.cocos2d-x.org/cocos2d-x/en/editors_and_tools/cocosCLTool.html this to make new project, after i create new project folders comes up, and i code inside proj.win32 where i found a sln file. I've succesfull in creating simple windows game project using win32 all works fine.

but How can i do this with android game project? did i make it right on installation or i miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've succeeded in creating a simple windows game project using win32
>   all works fine.

Now You want to port/deploy your game on Android.

**What is your native code build-system?**

You can find this in your `gradle.properties` file that is inside `proj.android` folder.

By default `cocos2d-x 3.17` using ndk-build but `cocos2d-x 3.17.1` using cmake.

- If `ndk-build`, native code will be compiled by Android.mk. Add all your `.cpp` file in `Android.mk`(find Android.mk inside jni folder) under `LOCAL_SRC_FILES` tag.
- If `cmake`, native code will be compiled by CMakeLists.txt. Add your `.cpp` and `.h` file in `CMakeLists.txt`(find CMakeLists.txt inside your project) under list of cross-platforms source files and header files.

Now you can build apk by using [Cocos command-line tool](https://docs.cocos2d-x.org/cocos2d-x/en/editors_and_tools/cocosCLTool.html) or Android Studio.

Comment: ah i get it now, thanks sir, ill update you soon i get it correct